# piping files from tar to a command

Tags: linux, tar

I need to untar a multiple-file archive. And I have to use a binary to do the actual writing.

With a single file archive, I'm happy with

```
tar -Oxvf singlefile.tgz | writer filename
```

for multiple files, tar has a `--to-command` option that pipes each file to a specified command. Sounds good but what about the file names?

```
>tar xvf test.tgz --to-command='writer' 2> /dev/null
tets1
test2
test3
```

`tar` seems to output the filenames to its stdout, and I couldn't find a way to get the filenames within the command.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you read the [tar man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tar) and the GNU tar [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/s/tar/manual/html_node/Writing-to-an-External-Program.html#SEC84) ?

You might also be interested by [tardy](http://tardy.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: oh, that link helps. They don't cover the environment in the man pages. Thanks

Comment: I did not understood your real overall goal. I'm guessing you want to process tar archive, and `tardy` might help (but I am not sure).

Comment: nope, I just needed to be told about TAR_FILENAME. Thanks again

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch , if you can put more of the details into your answer, I'll try to give you a +1. I like answers that are self-contained if possible.

Answer (score 3):

If you use the `--to-command` flag, various pieces of metadata about the process are made available in the environment. Running `tar -xf file.tar --to-command=env` gives:

```
TAR_VERSION=1.28
TAR_ARCHIVE=file.tar
TAR_VOLUME=1
TAR_BLOCKING_FACTOR=20
TAR_FORMAT=gnu
TAR_FILETYPE=f
TAR_MODE=0644
TAR_FILENAME=file1.txt
TAR_REALNAME=file1.txt
TAR_UNAME=james_pic
TAR_GNAME=users
TAR_ATIME=1501586107.32746318
TAR_MTIME=1492550943
TAR_CTIME=1501586107.32746318
TAR_SIZE=12345
TAR_UID=1001
TAR_GID=1000
```

For your purposes, you'll probably want `TAR_FILENAME`