# zgrep tar.gz file with file location results & match

Tags: bash, grep

I'm trying to scan 60gb of data to find what keywords are in each file.  Regular Grep -R is way too slow.  Takes about 20mins per search.

Currently tried

> zgrep -ai "string" file.tar.gz

and

> tar -zxf file.tar.gz -O | grep -Ri "string"

The results are missing the file location.  I need the file location then results just like doing a standard grep.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You say that "grep -R is too slow" and imply that you can avoid that slowness using zgrep. That doesn't make any sense. Either the data is compressed or its not. The choice between those two tools doesn't have anything to do with speed.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/13992867/1563960