# Method to get file byte offsets (and lengths) in tar files

Tags: python, linux, file, tar

I have a large tar file containing millions of files.  For efficiency reasons I don't want to untar the files to disk.

Rather, given a desired filename, I would like to write a script e.g. Python to pull the relevant chunk of data from the tar file.

Is there an easy way to create an index telling me the starting byte and length of every file in the tar file e.g. I could dump out to disk as an index for use in the abovementioned Python script?

Maybe the tar command can do this but I'm not seeing anything obvious in the man page.

The tar is not compressed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not use zip/7z/xz/etc which have indexes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the benefit of others with a similar use case (i.e. wanting to build an index enabling random access on a tar file) in the end I adapted a handy utility at http://fomori.org/blog/?p=391  the essence of which is (in Python):

> ```
> fp = open('index.txt', 'w')
> ctr = 0
> with tarfile.open(tarfname, 'r') as db:
>   for tarinfo in db:
>      currentseek = tarinfo.offset_data
>      rec = "%d\t%d\t%d\t%s\n" % (ctr,tarinfo.offset_data, tarinfo.size, tarinfo.name)
>      fp.write(rec)
>      ctr += 1
>      if ctr % 1000 == 0:
>         db.members = []
> fp.close()
> ```

The check at %1000 conserves RAM. I'm sure this could be neater.

Answer (score 4):

Python code performs not very well. I use below awk scripts to do that for a big tar file.

```
tar -tvf <tar-file> -R | awk '
BEGIN{
  getline;
  f=$8;
  s=$5;
}
{
  offset = int($2) * 512 - and((s+511), -512)
  print offset,s,f;
  f=$8;
  s=$5;
}'
```

Comment: What `awk` is this for? `gawk` 5.0.0 errors with: `and: argument 1 negative value -512 is not allowed`

Comment: ah, support for negative operands was removed in 4.2: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Bitwise-Functions.html#index-gawk-57

Comment: Evidently from the bitwise `and` this is already assuming the number representation being used is two's complement, so I just replaced `-512` with `compl(512)+1` to get something working in gawk 5 with no worse assumptions :D

Comment: `tar -tvf <tar-file> | awk '{printf("%d %d %s", N+512, $3, $6); for (i = 7; i <= NF; i++) { printf(" %s", $(i)) }; printf("\n"); N+=$3 + (512 - ($3 % 512)) + 512}'` Should be compatible with busybox (note lack of -R), and account for files with whitespaces (but not newlines) in names.