# list all tar files and search for a string and output in a txt file

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I have to list all the tar files in a directory and search for a string in the listed tar files and place the output in a txt file.

I have tried this below

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in `ls /dbhome/Logs/*.tar.gz`
do
    echo $i
done

while read filename
do 
    tar -xOf ${i} "$filename" | grep 'mitst' | sed "s|^|$filename:|" 
done < <(tar -tf ${i} | grep -v '/$') > test2.txt
```

I am able to list the tar files but search pattern did not work. test2.txt comes with empty files always.

Comment: GNU tar has `--to-command` and GNU grep has `--label`: cf. https://stackoverflow.com/a/42258011/10971581

Comment: Please don't parse the output of `ls` and avoid parsing the output of printing file names whenever possible. It is difficult to guess from your code what you are trying to achieve. I suggest to [edit] your question and add a description based on an example: What .tar files do you have? What files are there in the .tar files? What files from the archives do you want to process? What output do you expect? It might help to test smaller parts. Show the output of `tar -tf ${i} | grep -v '/$'`. Is it what you expect? Or insert a line `set -x` before the `for` loop and show/check the output.

Comment: btw, instead of `for ... do ... done; while ... do ... done`, try: `for ... do while ... do ... done; done`